# Glue status shows status succeeded but redshift views not refreshing

Tags: python, amazon-redshift, aws-glue

I am using glue to refresh redshift views and tables. Tables are stored in S3 and I am picking up those tables and writing in redhshit.
It is working when I provide a single table as input(without any loops or defining variables) but when I am trying to loop in through S3 paths it is not refreshing redshift. The status in glue UI shows succeeded.

Below is the code:

```
import sys
from awsglue.transforms import *
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from awsglue.job import Job
from awsglue.dynamicframe import DynamicFrame
import logging

logging.basicConfig(format = format)
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

## @params: [TempDir, JOB_NAME]
args = getResolvedOptions(sys.argv, ['TempDir','JOB_NAME'])


sc = SparkContext()
glueContext = GlueContext(sc)
spark = glueContext.spark_session
job = Job(glueContext)
job.init(args['JOB_NAME'], args)

#dictionary containing normalized table path and table name
normalized_table_dictionary={"s3://test/test_data1/":"test_table1","s3://test/test_data1/":"test_table2"}

#@params database,view,user
view_dbname = "test_view"
table_dbname = "test_table"
database = "test_database"
a_user="a_user"
b_user="b_user"


for s3_path,table_name in normalized_table_dictionary.items():
    normalized_table = ''
    redshift_view = ''
    normalized_table = table_name
    redshift_view = "test_"+normalized_table

    inputGDF = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame_from_options(connection_type = "s3", connection_options = {"paths": [f"{s3_path}"]}, format = "parquet")
    
    pre_query = f"truncate table {table_dbname}.{normalized_table} if exists;"

    logger.info(pre_query)
    
    
    post_query = f"begin;drop materialized view if exists {view_dbname}.{redshift_view};create materialized view {view_dbname}.{redshift_view} as select * from {table_dbname}.{normalized_table};grant select on {view_dbname}.{redshift_view} to {b_user};end;"
    
    logger.info(post_query)
    ## Write data to redshift
    datasink1 = glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_jdbc_conf(frame = inputGDF, catalog_connection =f"{a_user}", connection_options = {"preactions":pre_query,"dbtable": f"{table_dbname}.{normalized_table}", "database": f"{database}"}, redshift_tmp_dir = args["TempDir"],transformation_ctx = "datasink1")
    logger.info('datasink1',datasink1)

    datasink2 = glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_jdbc_conf(frame = inputGDF, catalog_connection = f"{a_user}", connection_options = {"dbtable": f"{table_dbname}.{normalized_table}", "database": f"{database}","postactions":post_query}, redshift_tmp_dir = args["TempDir"],transformation_ctx = "datasink2")
    
    logger.info('datasink1',datasink2)
job.commit()
```

Answer (score 0):

well i was facing the same problem. turns out the problem was with redshift.

Try to login into RS and perform your query again.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33937609)